# Tauri mousemove handler is janky

Tags: tauri

I want to build a very simple tauri application where the user can draw on top of an image they uploaded. I am using the `mousemove` event to record the x and y coordinates of user's mouse pointer and draw a path on the canvas. This seems to work perfectly when I run the code on any browser (here's a working [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jnrh5e?file=index.html)), however, on Tauri, the experience is quite janky. The path starts drawing, then there's some lag during which nothing is drawn on screen, and after a few seconds the path appears.

Here's the main code for the `mousemove` handler. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/Dinika/image-annotate) that uses tauri (along with a short video demoing the jankiness).

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
let drawing = false;

function startDrawing() {
    drawing = true;
}

function draw(e) {
    if (!drawing) return;
    console.log('DRAW After return');

    let { x, y } = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
}
```